# What is the best way to store multiple Axios requests in VueX?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm new to Vue and i would like to know how can i get data from multiple requests , store it in an object, and then preform some manipulations to the data...(format dates, add currency properties, etc..)

For example:

Suppose these are my requests:

'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'

'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2'

'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3'

So i want to do something like :

1. Set a state variable to store all the id's for looping it later on

   ```
    state: {
       ids:[1,2,3],
       posts:[],
       alteredPostsArr :[]
     },
   ```
2. Loop the requests and store all the data

   ```
    var dataStored = [];
    var ids = this.state.ids
      for(var i=0; i< ids.length; i++){
           axios
           .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+ids[i])
           .then(function(response){
             dataStored.push(response.data)
             console.log(response.data);
           })

         }
    this.state.posts = dataStored // store all results
   ```
3. Create a function that manipulates the data... something like

   ```
   setDate :function(data){ // loop over this.state.posts


      for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){

             var newDataObj = {
                "userId": data[i].userId,
                "id": data[i].id,
                "title": data[i].title,
                "body": data[i].body,
                "date":new Date(),

               }
          this.state.alteredPostsArr.push(newDataObj )
       }
   ```

   }

I've look into vuex tutorials but i don't understand where should i put the axios requests loop... so i've tried to put it in the Actions, like here, but i get empty arrays.....

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
          state: {

            posts:[],
            ids:[1,2,3],
            alteredPostsArr:[],

        },
          methods:{

            setDate:function(data){
              // loop over this.state.posts

              for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){

                    var newDataObj = {
                        "userId": data[i].userId,
                        "id": data[i].id,
                        "title": data[i].title,
                        "body": data[i].body,
                        "date":new Date(),

                      }
                  this.state.alteredPostsArr.push(newDataObj )
              }

          }
          },

          actions: {
            loadPosts ({ commit }) {
              var dataStored = [];
              var ids = this.state.ids
              for(var i=0; i< ids.length; i++){
                axios
                .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+ids[i])
                .then(function(response){
                  dataStored.push(response.data)

                })

              }
              this.state.posts = dataStored // store all results
            }
          },
          mutations: {
            SET_POSTS (state, posts) {
              state.posts = posts
            }
  }
```

Comment: please fix your example, there is no `methods` section in Vuex store

Comment: I wasn't aware that it doesn't....so where do i put the methods?